# Recursive call affecting parent method variables?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am building nested comments.
My AJAX script gets a list of comments like follows and expands them -

```
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || myOb.readyState == "complete")   {
        // EVAL
        var comments = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

        // POPULATE
        var comm = "<ul>";
        for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)    {               
            if(comments[i].replyto == 0)    {
                comm = comm + expand(property, comments, i);
            }
        }
        comm = comm + "</ul>";
        // DISPLAY
        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = comm;
    }
```

Here, the `expand` function is recursive, and seems to be causing trouble -

```
function expand(property, comments, k)  {
    var comm = "";

    // PRINT MAIN COMMENTS
    comm = comm + "<li>";
        // print otherparent comment data

        // replies
        comm = comm + "<ul>";
        for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)    {
            // is a reply?
            if(comments[i].replyto == comments[k].id)   {
                comm = comm + expand(property, comments, i);
            }
        }
        comm = comm + "</ul>";

    comm = comm + "</li>";
    return comm;
}
```

This script ends up giving my only the first `comments` array element (with it's respective sub-comments). But if i remove the recursive bit of code, I don't face that problem (also, i don
t get any sub-comments)..

```
function expand(property, comments, k)  {
    var comm = "";

    // PRINT MAIN COMMENTS
    comm = comm + "<li>";
        // print otherparent comment data

        // replies
        comm = comm + "<ul>";
        /*
        for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)    {
            // is a reply?
            if(comments[i].replyto == comments[k].id)   {
                comm = comm + expand(property, comments, i);
            }
        }
        */
        comm = comm + "</ul>";

    comm = comm + "</li>";
    return comm;
}
```

I set two alerts in the `eval` function, one each before and after the `expand` call:

```
        for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)    {               
            if(comments[i].replyto == 0)    {
                alert(i);
                comm = comm + expand(property, comments, i);
                alert(i);
            }
        }
```

Both gave me different values of `i`. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to make "i" a local variable:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)    {
```

That's **really** important.